# Assets Order Effected by Eager Loading

Tags: entries, assets, order, eager-loading

I am trying to eager load an asset field that contains 4 images.

When I originally set my entries the order was not affected as written below:

```
{% set products = craft.entries.section('products') %}
```

I then went and changed my `set` to leverage eager loading and upon doing so the order of the images was pretty much randomized throughout the template:

```
{% set products = craft.entries({
    section: 'products',
    with: [
        ['productImages', {
        withTransforms: ['small']
        }],
        'colorSelection']
}) %}
```

I then tried to add an order param next to `withTransforms` which did not have any effect either.

Is this a known issue?

UPDATE:

```
    <li
        data-left="{{product.productImages[1].getUrl('small')}}"
        data-center="{{product.productImages[0].getUrl('small')}}"
        data-right="{{product.productImages[2].getUrl('small')}}"
        class="product"
    >
        <a href="{{product.url}}">
            <img class="product-image" src="{{product.productImages[0].getUrl('small')}}" alt="">
            <h4>{{gender}} - {{product.displayTitle}}</h4>
            <span>{{product.price}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Is how we are templating out each entry. Both provide a different order of assets.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing in my test case.  Can you update the question to show how you're displaying the images?

Comment: @BradBell updated it as requested.

Comment: Comes out in the proper fixed order with that template code on my end.     ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @BradBell I'm seeing something similar in one of our builds. Can we send a support ticket? Or what's the best way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: @RobErskine sure, shoot a database backup and template we can reproduce with over to support@craftcms.com

Comment: This bug was fixed in [Craft 2.6.2778](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2778).